# Error when using an inner variable of a component

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am using Thermal Power Library from Modelon. There is a condenser component in the Thermal Power Library which is used for the modeling of power plants.
The default heat transfer area for the wall_2 in the condenser component is `0.8*A_heat_tot`, the variable of `A_heat_tot` is an inner variable in the condenser component, but when I try to use this variable, there is an error showing that this variable isn’t defined.

My question is that If I can use the inner variable directly. If not, how should I use it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: You need to address the variable with its full path, i.e. `wall_2.A_heat_tot`.

`A_heat_tot` is define in `StandardWall` and can thus be referred to directly inside the class. However, when you are making changes to `A_heat` from outside the instance of `StandardWall` (i.e. outside `wall_2`) you must point to the **origin** of `A_heat_tot` since it is otherwise not known in the scope from which you are trying to use it.

Likewise, if you are making the modification in you simulation model (`Preheater_Model_Validation2`) you must use the full path, i.e. `hex.wall_2.A_heat = hex.A_heat_tot`

By the way, this has nothing to do with the `inner` qualifier in the Modelica language.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But the problem is that `A_heat_tot` is defined in the `Condenser` component, so I think it could be referred to directly.

Comment: I would recommend trying to use the full qualified path, Rene should be right here. E.g. `ModelName.ComponentName.ComponentName.AttributeName`, note that i started from the very top level which is your model. If the variable is not protected you should be able to access it from anywhere.